inkscape linked SVG PDF export
I want to know if it is possible to export an inkscape SVG that contains a linked SVG as image to PDF without loosing vectorial of the linked one.
As an example, you will find a PDF and its SVG sources here
Thank for your help by advance 

Based on the info in the question what does this have to do with Ubuntu? There is no mention of it.
